# How to determine allocated blocks on an NTFS disk

Tags: filesystems, allocation, ntfs, disk

Is there a way of determining which clusters on an NTFS disk are allocated? I'm thinking along the lines of the display you see on a defrag program before you kick off the defrag itself.

I guess you could parse the MFT but it strikes me that this could take a long time on a system with potentially hundreds of thousands of files.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is to get the drive bitmap with I/O controls. There is a nice open source defragmenter that can give you a good example on how to do it: [JkDefrag](http://www.kessels.biz/JkDefrag/) (NOTE: the MyDefrag is not open source). [Jeffey Wall's WebLog](http://blogs.msdn.com/jeffrey_wall/archive/2004/09/13/229137.aspx) also contains a bunch of links that might interest you.

Another interesting article about the [`FSCTL_GET_VOLUME_BITMAP`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897427.aspx) I/O control is provided by microsoft.